# Patching a hole in an interior block wall

Tags: repair, concrete, interior

We have a bathroom that had the shower valves in an exterior block wall (OLD construction, lake cabin).  The valves sprung a leak and the plumber had to knock out the block around the valves to get access to replace them leaving a roughly 12" hole around the valves.  How do I patch this?  Nothing I've researched appears to fit this situation.

Comment: Come on John,  give us something to work with... like a picture.

Comment: Are the valves still there or do you just want to recreate a smooth wall surface? makes a slight difference in approach.

Comment: New valves are installed, so I can't just shoot the cavity with foam.  I've got to keep the valves free.  The wall is simply painted block.  Construction was probably '50s.  I'm guessing that they installed the original valves as they laid the wall up.

Comment: I'll go over tomorrow and snap a couple of photos.